# Does Jquery ui accordion have valid accessible markup

Tags: jquery-ui, accessibility

I am developing my own semantic web-accessible jquery accordion plugin. I observe other popular plugins and found an issue in JqueryUi accordion plugin. In its example header role is changed to "tab". So the result is h3 element with role attr "tab". But I noticed for several times that changing the native role is non conforming. Me resource is https://specs.webplatform.org/html-aria/webspecs/master/ and the main quote is: "Web developers must not use the ARIA role and aria-* attributes in a manner that conflicts with the semantics described in the Document conformance requirements for use of ARIA attributes in HTML table."
So, jQueryUi is not valid?

Answer (score 1):

That is not correct. As can be read in the 1.1 version of the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#h-host_general_conflict the host semantics can be overridden and the ARIA role takes precedence (MUST).

```
 When a WAI-ARIA role is provided, user agents must use the semantic of the
 WAI-ARIA role for processing, not the native semantic, unless the role
 requires WAI-ARIA states and properties whose attributes are explicitly
 forbidden on the native element by the host language.
```

Because there is no native tab role in HTML, it would be reasonable to conclude that it even meets the SHOULD portions of ARIA (but this is more open to interpretation)

Comment: But what if the user wants to navigate by headings. He could not, because  the accordion headings have another role. And what is the purpose of using headings if their roles are rewritten? It's confusing.

Comment: Semantically, something cannot both be a header and a tab (accordion) at the same time, so this is ok

Comment: So, in jquery-ui example headings can be just replaced with div. What is the purpose of using headings? I do not understand.